# How did the Atmospheric Steam Engine do work?

Tags: thermodynamics, vacuum, gas

Hello everyone and happy thanksgiving!

The first workable steam engine was the Newcomen Atmospheric Engine (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newcomen_atmospheric_engine). It worked through the following process: Steam would fill up a chamber with a piston in it. Cold water would be injected into this chamber, which caused the steam to condense, creating a partial vacuum. The pressure of the atmosphere (hence "atmospheric engine") would push downwards on the piston, hence raising water.

However, when I learned thermodynamics, i learned that free expansion of a gas against a vacuum (even when there is a piston in between) does no work. Can someone help reconcile my intuition here? Because the Newcomen engine, despite involving a gas (the atmosphere) pushing against a piston in contact with a vacuum, certainly does perform work!

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the exact words "free expansion against a vacuum".

In the atmospheric steam engine, expansion isn't free - it's loaded by the force of moving the engine and the engine's load. It's not against a vacuum - it's against a piston which moves slowly against force. In this way work is done.

Free expansion against vacuum usually suggests opening a valve directly into vacuum, or breaking a membrane between a vacuum and pressure. When a piston that has a load of force is interposed, the expansion is anything but free.

Comment: I think I understand this, but I was hoping to follow up with a question. Specifically, what do you mean by "loading"?

Here's how I understand it. The push of the atmospheric pressure against the piston isn't free because the piston itself is linked to a mechanism that is pulling up some mass against the force of gravity. Free expansion does no work because there are no molecules for the gas under pressure to "push" out of the way in the vacuum. But here, the gas molecules of the atmosphere have to "push" a piston which is lifting a load that has some weight.

Comment: Pretty much. If you had a massless, frictionless, unloaded piston that would just slam to the other side of the cylinder, that *would* be free expansion doing no work.

Answer (score 0):

For *partial vacuum* read *reduced pressure below atmospheric* to avoid the misleading reference to a vacuum.

When such a state is reached there is a pressure difference across the cylinder which results in a net force on the cylinder which is harnessed to do useful work.